# A word beginning with "L" that means moved a lot

Tags: single-word-requests

I am sorry, I asked my question earlier in an answer box.  I am writing my life story and I have looked hither and yonder for a word starting with "L" meaning moved a lot.

My theme is Lies, loss and ____________? (My parents moved a lot when I was a child to adult)  A few moves were military but most of them were not.  I had been in 15 schools when I graduated from high school.

Rachel

Comment: Although the "L" comes with the second syllable, "relocation" seems to fit, and because "re" is a prefix , "location," quickly exerts itself: Lies, Loss and Relocation. Another possibility might be Lies, Loss and Last Goodbyes (or views, etc.)

Comment: Lies, Loss and Leaving ?

Comment: ... locales? ...

Comment: @JamesRandom Our posts crossed. Feel free to post yours as an answer as well.

Comment: At the risk of changing your story and being an optimist, I really like **liberation**. But commenting rather than answering because, although it’s poetic and optimistic, it may not fit your story.

Comment: "Luggage" can imply moving.

Comment: A thesaurus comes up with "locomotive", "liquid", "loose".  Or you could simply use "leave".

Comment: @Knotell - The "sentence" was stated in the original question:  "Lies, loss, and ____".  Like a book title.

Answer (score 3):

Consider *leavings*.

> **leave** *verb*
>   1 Go away from.
>   ‘she left London on June 6’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leave)

Every time you move (relocate), you *leave* the old place. The gerund *leaving* can be made plural. Also, using *leavings* instead of *leave* avoids having to explain why you're not talking about taking time off work.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but a serious suggestion: try a different initial for the alliteration?

*Loss* can become ***grief***, the leavings ***goodbyes*** … alas this leaves you wanting for the first item. I was only able to find ***guile*** as a substitute, which isn’t quite the same (and might leave the whole thing sounding too intellectual or pretentious, sorry).

Answer (score -1):

Following Zan700’s idea of considering words
that have a syllable *beginning* with ‘L’, I suggest ***wanderlust***. 
It might not apply perfectly to job-related (or -required) moves;
I don’t know your story or your tolerance for poetic license.

> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/wanderlust):
>
>   A strong desire to travel.
>   *‘a man consumed by wanderlust’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wanderlust):
>
>   A very strong or irresistible impulse to travel.
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wanderlust):
>
>   Someone who has
>   **wanderlust**
>   has a strong desire to travel.
>   *His wanderlust would not allow him to stay long in one spot.*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wanderlust):
>
>   a strong wish to travel